# "Dad's corner" or "dads' corner"

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

Which is right: *dad's corner* or *dads' corner*? I see *dad's corner* used regularly so I am assuming that's right, but in my mind *dad's* is singular whereas the corner belongs to multiple dads as it's a place for dads to go to meet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct but they have different meanings:

- Dad's corner - a corner for a father
- Dads' corner - a corner for many fathers

A useful comparison is *Father's Day* (or *Mother's Day*). It's a day to appreciate many fathers, but is written this way as it's a usually day to appreciate one father at a time. This is a generic plural.

Another example is [*Dad's Army*](http://www.dadsarmy.co.uk/), the name of a sitcom about the Home Guard during the Second World War.

Comment: *Private Eye* had a long correspondence about whether one part of the letters column should be called "Pedants' Corner' or 'Pedant's Corner'.  It is now called 'Pedantry Corner'.

Comment: If there were any sanity in the world, we'd write 'dads corner' and allow the context to determine the sense.

Comment: @Barrie: like *Finnegans Wake*?